# Why doesn't my Laravel conditional whereHas query work?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a conditional `User` search function. There are three filters that a user could select to search on:

- user name
- company name associated with user
- role name associated with user

*In the following example I have put all the filters in the array `$searchFilters` for simplicity.*

I only want Laravel to search the filters that are present in the array.

**The code**

```
$q = request()->q;
$searchWildcard = '%' . $q . '%';
$searchFilters = ['name', 'roles', 'company'];

$users = User::when(in_array('roles', $searchFilters), function ($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
      $query->whereHas('roles', function($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
         $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $searchWildcard);
      });
   })->when(in_array('company', $searchFilters), function($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
      $query->whereHas('company', function($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
         $query->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $searchWildcard);
       });
   })->when(in_array('name', $searchFilters), function($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
      $query->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $searchWildcard);
});
```

The first part of the query works: It retrieves the roles based on the search query by the user, but it doesn't work for the company name or user name.

**Edit**

It only doesn't work for the company name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `orWhere` condition is inside another `where` so I imagine it won't work as expected.

I would suggest changing your `whereHas` to `orWhereHas` and then changing the `orWhere` inside it to `where`:

```
$users = User::when(in_array('roles', $searchFilters), function ($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
    $query->whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $searchWildcard);
    });
})->when(in_array('company', $searchFilters), function ($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
    $query->orWhereHas('company', function ($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $searchWildcard);
    });
})->when(in_array('name', $searchFilters), function ($query) use ($searchWildcard) {
    $query->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $searchWildcard);
});
```

Comment: @BvdL Glad I could help!